# How to pass a non-nullable type to a function with a nullable parameter?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety, generic-function

A nullable type can be checked and cast to a non-nullable type, but the other way around is quite difficult.

For example:

```
str1: String? = ""
// if str1 not null
str2: String = str1

str3: String? = str2 // This works!
```

In my case I'm talking about a function with an Array parameter in which the contents could be null, but the contents of the Array I want to pass to the function is non-nullable. That does not work:

```
var var1: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(10)

var var2: Array<String> = var1.filterNotNull().toTypedArray()

var var3: Array<String?> = var2 // This does not work!
```

My question is how to make this work?

I am able to cast the array to a nullable array, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: In Kotlin type system `String` is a subtype of `String?`, so it should work fine. See https://pl.kotl.in/gnaZrD9Xm

Comment: But Array<String> does not seem to be a subtype of Array<String?>. That's the problem.

Comment: where exactly are you using array<String> in the above question?

Comment: @letsstartcoding I updated my question, the actual case is now added.

Comment: have you tried using Kotlin Collection Lists?

Comment: @sd_master92 Yes, generics in Kotlin are _invariant_ by default. If you declared a function with an `Array<String>` argument, then it will accept only `Array<String>` (it could have accepted subtypes of `Array` if there were any, but the generic argument should remain same - `String`). If you want it to accept both `Array<String?>` and `Array<String>` arguments you need to define it as _contravariant_ (`Array<in String>`) or _covariant_ (`Array<out String?>`).

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, arrays are invariant, which means that an array of a given type can't be assigned to an array of its parent type. That's why you can't assign `Array<String>` to `Array<String?>`, even if `String` is a subclass of `String?`. For this to work, you should either

1. use lists, which are covariant:

```
var var1: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(10)
var var2: List<String> = var1.filterNotNull()
var var3: List<String?> = var2  // Now works
```

2. cast the array to a nullable array, as you're doing:

```
var var1: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(10)
var var2: Array<String> = var1.filterNotNull().toTypedArray()
var var3: Array<String?> = var2 as Array<String?>  // Now works
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1: String? = ""

// if str1 not null
var str2: String = str1 ?: ""

var str3: String? = str2
```

> Try This, Here ?: stands for checking if a value is null or not, if
> not null its fine, but if it gets null you can set a default value in
> it, that why i used a default value "" in it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But I think you understood my question wrong. I'm talking about the 3rd step which is not working out. (str3: String? = str2)

Answer (score 0):

what I can say is,

```
//This value can hold null values 
str1: String? = ""

// if str1 not null, store values in str2
// so, now str2 holds NOT NULL VALUES
str2: String = str1

// Now by default since str2 is NOT NULL
// All the values being passed inside str2 will always be NOT NULL
// 
str3: String? = str2 // This does not work
```

str3 will only throw an error in case str2 is null but it is not possible since as you said, it goes through a null check.

the workaround looks something like this.

1. This is one possible solution, i.e. defining str2 as a Nullable string

```
str1 : String? = ""

str2 : String? = str1

str3 : String? = str2
```

2. Another solution would be, putting null check at str2, because since str2 is not null str3 will by default be Not Null.

```
str1 : String? = ""

str2 : String = str1 ?: ""

str3 : String = str2
```

**Update**

As per the updated question,

```
// A list of nulls
var var1: List<String?> = listOf(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)

//Mutable List to hold not null values or filter out null values
var var2: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
for (i in var1) var2.add(i ?: "")

//var3 will always be not null
var var3: List<String?> = var2
```

Answer (score 0):

No answer actually seems to explain at the moment *why* arrays are invariant (and so `Array<String>` is not a subtype of `Array<String?>`). If

```kotlin
var var2: Array<String> = var1.filterNotNull().toTypedArray()

var var3: Array<String?> = var2 // This does not work!
```

worked, then you could do

```kotlin
var3[0] = null
val x: String = var2[0]
```

Because `var3` and `var2` refer to the same object, this puts `null` into an `Array<String>` and then retrieves it as a non-nullable `String`. This obviously breaks null-safety.

It's better to only "cast the array to a nullable array, as you're doing" if you are sure your code can never do this.